# In scikit's precision_recall_curve, why does thresholds have a different dimension from recall and precision?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I want to see how precision and recall vary with the threshold (not just with each other)

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(500, n_jobs = -1);  
model.fit(X_train, y_train);  
probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]  
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, probas)  
print len(precision)   
print len(thresholds)
```

Returns:

```
283  
282
```

I can, therefore, not plot them together. Any clues as to why this might be the case?

Comment: To split N elements in 3 groups you need 2 thresholds, that's why. The generalization is for `n` bins you need `n-1` decision functions (thresholds in this case).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this problem, the last precision and the recall value should be ignored
The last precision and recall values are always 1. and 0. respectively and do not have a corresponding threshold.

For example here is a solution :

```
def plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold(precisions, recall, thresholds): 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize= (8,5))
    plt.plot(thresholds, precisions[:-1], "b--", label="Precision")
    plt.plot(thresholds, recall[:-1], "g-", label="Recall")
    plt.legend()

plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold(precision, recall, thresholds)
```

These values should are there so that the plot starts at the y-axis (x=0) when you are plotting precision vs recall.